# Javascript Function is unresponsive

Tags: javascript, html

This is the first time I'm making a web application (no previous Javascript or HTML experience). Ive been stuck on this for a while now and I need help. I was trying to make a Basic Tick Tack Toe. When you click on the Letters nothing happens , when they are suppose to change according to
the move number (vMove). General comments on my code also appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```js
let vBoard = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"] ;
let vMove = 1 ;
function clickFunction(Input) {
  if (vMove == 1 || vMove == 3 || vMove == 5 || vMove == 7 || vMove == 9) {
    vBoard[Input] = "X";
      document.getElementById("Cell" + Input).innerHTML = vBoard[Input];
    }
    else if (vMove == 2 || vMove == 4 || vMove == 6 || vMove == 8) {
    vBoard[Input] = "0";
      document.getElementById("Cell" + Input).innerHTML = vBoard[Input];
    }
    else if (vBoard[0] == vBoard[1] && vBoard[0] == vBoard[2] ){
      document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
    }
    else if (vBoard[3] == vBoard[4] && vBoard[3] == vBoard[5] ){
      document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
    }
    else if (vBoard[6] == vBoard[7] && vBoard[6] == vBoard[8] ){
      document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
    }
    else if (vBoard[0] == vBoard[3] && vBoard[0] == vBoard[6] ){
      document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
    }
    else if (vBoard[1] == vBoard[4] && vBoard[1] == vBoard[7] ){
      document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
    }
    else if (vBoard[2] == vBoard[5] && vBoard[2] == vBoard[8] ){
      document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
    }
    else if (vBoard[0] == vBoard[4] && vBoard[0] == vBoard[8] ){
      document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
    }
    else if (vBoard[2] == vBoard[4] && vBoard[2] == vBoard[6] ){
      document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
    }
    vMove = vMove + 1 ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ttt.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td id="Cell0" onclick="clickFunction(0)">A</td>
   <td id="Cell1" onclick="clickFunction(1)">B</td>
   <td id="Cell2" onclick="clickFunction(2)">C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td id="Cell3" onclick="clickFunction(3)">D</td>
   <td id="Cell4" onclick="clickFunction(4)">E</td>
   <td id="Cell5" onclick="clickFunction(5)">F</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td id="Cell6" onclick="clickFunction(6)">F</td>
   <td id="Cell7" onclick="clickFunction(7)">G</td>
   <td id="Cell8" onclick="clickFunction(8)">H</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

Comment: The snippet works for me in Firefox. I don't get a victory condition but each click does change the letter `X` or `0` (alternates between the two).

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me in Safari 13.1 in terms of the switching to an X or an O howeveryou can't see the response because you haven't got any html for the response, you could try adding this to your html:

```
<p id="Response"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let vBoard = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"] ;
let vMove = 1 ;
function clickFunction(Input) {
  if (vMove >= 1 && vMove <= 9) {
    vBoard[Input] = vMove % 2 === 1 ? "X" : "O";
    document.getElementById("Cell" + Input).innerHTML = vBoard[Input];
  }
  vMove = vMove + 1;
  
  if (
    (vBoard[0] == vBoard[1] && vBoard[0] == vBoard[2]) || 
    (vBoard[3] == vBoard[4] && vBoard[3] == vBoard[5]) ||
    (vBoard[6] == vBoard[7] && vBoard[6] == vBoard[8]) ||
    (vBoard[0] == vBoard[3] && vBoard[0] == vBoard[6]) ||
    (vBoard[1] == vBoard[4] && vBoard[1] == vBoard[7]) ||
    (vBoard[2] == vBoard[5] && vBoard[2] == vBoard[8]) ||
    (vBoard[0] == vBoard[4] && vBoard[0] == vBoard[8]) ||
    (vBoard[2] == vBoard[4] && vBoard[2] == vBoard[6])
  ) {
    document.getElementById("Response").innerHTML = "We have a winner";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ttt.css">
</head>
<body>
  <table>
  <tr>
   <td id="Cell0" onclick="clickFunction(0)">A</td>
   <td id="Cell1" onclick="clickFunction(1)">B</td>
   <td id="Cell2" onclick="clickFunction(2)">C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td id="Cell3" onclick="clickFunction(3)">D</td>
   <td id="Cell4" onclick="clickFunction(4)">E</td>
   <td id="Cell5" onclick="clickFunction(5)">F</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td id="Cell6" onclick="clickFunction(6)">F</td>
   <td id="Cell7" onclick="clickFunction(7)">G</td>
   <td id="Cell8" onclick="clickFunction(8)">H</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <div id="Response"></div>
</body>
```

This way you don't repeat yourself too much